# How do I loop through multiple files using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple files whose format of filename like: `qs_l2b_yearday.nc`; for example: `1s_l2b_2008031.nc`.

I'm trying to use shell script to download these files from remote server, but unfortunately I cannot find a way to do that. With my limited understanding the code should loop through years as outside loop and loop through days as inside loop. And the core code should use scp to download the file from server. I have figured out how to download one of those files using scp, but need some help to solve the "for loop" problem.

Year is from 1999 to 2009. Day is from 001 to 365

Comment: Show us what you've tried, even if it doesn't work. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, it's much better if you can give us something to critique and correct.

Comment: Is the 1st character of the filename "q" or "1"?

Comment: Sorry for that. I've tried to use scp to download one or some of those files.         Like scp user@server.com: /directory/directory/filename /User/mypcdirectory/. But I want to use for loop to download all files like        for year in {1999..2009}                                                                                 for day in {001..364}                                                                                                   scp user@server.com: /directory/qs_l2b_yearday.nc                                         done

Comment: it should be q, sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard to scp multiple files like so

```
scp user@somehost:/some/path/to/files/qs_l2b_*.nc /some/target/directory/
```

Comment: Its probably better to put single quotes around the paths.  Aside from the possibility of embedded whitespace, the current shell could attempt to expand the wildcard.